# Add notnull constraint to a column of an existing table

Tags: oracle

How to add notnull constraint to a column of an existing table in which no value is yet inserted i.e. only table is created and now i want to alter the table
i am writing the following query

```
       ALTER TABLE TABLENAME MODIFY COLUMNAME DATATYPE NOT NULL;
```

but oracle is throwing error "invalid alter table option"

Comment: ALTER TABLE TABLENAME 
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype NOT NULL;

Comment: @Khalil, that's not valid syntax - `COLUMN` is not needed (or even allowed) in the `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY` command (except for the `SUBSTITUTABLE` option for object type columns). You would get `ORA-00905 missing keyword`.

Comment: Before Oracle 10g `COLUMN` is needed. This changed in oracle 10g and later.

Answer (score 1):

In an alter table you only have to specify what changes

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME MODIFY COLUMNAME NOT NULL;
```

As you don't change the datatype, you don't have to specify it again.